# PHP: How to dynamically change output in file

Tags: php

Redirect output do **minified.js** file

```
file_put_contents("minified.js", $packer->pack());
```

This redirects the output to the minified.js file. If I change anything in the code, the output is not updated in minified.js. I must always delete the content and run it again.

How can I do this dynamically and make the content in minified.js always replaced automatically?

Comment: Case 1: Check read/write permission
Case 2: File is updated but browser cache may be shows old file data.

Comment: Permission is allright and nobody change when i clear browser cache

Comment: Run this code then locally check minified.js with code editor, does it really being updated or not?

Comment: Ah, I see that when I open the file in file browser where file_put_contents (then minified.js again), the changes will take effect otherwise. Is there a way to make the file automatically restored? To respond to changes in another file.

Comment: You can use $OgFile = file_get_contents('minified.js');

Comment: Nope. Still does not change automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177870/discussion-between-smartpal-and-theczechtayen).

Comment: I've posted answer, You can check.

Answer (score 0):

Check the last modification time of the file where the original version is located.

```
$original_file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/main.js';

$last_modified = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($original_file));

file_put_contents($last_modified, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/date.txt');
$last_modified_read = file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/date.txt');

if(strtotime($last_modified_read) < strtotime($last_modified)){
  echo "Minify!";
  file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/date.txt', $last_modified);
}
```

[filemtime()](http://php.net/filemtime)

Comment: Please wait. I'll test it and help.

Comment: I just need to copy the output from minified.php to minified.js. Whenever the output in minified.php changes, so it automatically changes in minified.js, this is what I need.

Comment: I fixed it. Now work. I have not slept in 26 hours. Sorry for the mistake. It is enough to run this query with the help of a cron or .php file.

Comment: I'm trying it, but it still does not work. Still the content in minified.js does not change automatically until I open minified.php. I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of header function....
your code in [minified.php](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43567699#43567699) is...

code

```
<?php 

// Načteme config 
require_once("../functions/config.php"); 
// Načteme adresáře 
$Directories = JS_Directories(); 
// Načteme soubory z adresářů 
$Buffer = ""; 
foreach ($Directories as $Directory) { 
foreach(glob($Directory . "*.js") as $File) { 
$Buffer .= file_get_contents($File); 
} 
}; 
// Načteme minifikátor 
require_once("minifier.php"); 
// Spustíme minifikátor 
$packer = new Tholu\Packer\Packer($Buffer, 'Normal', true, false, true); 
// Nastavíme MIME typ
$presentFile = file_get_contents("minified.js"); //Get Old data then merge with new.
file_put_contents("minified.js", $presentFile.$packer->pack()); //Moved above header then merge.
header("Content-type: text/javascript"); 
// Výstup 
echo $packer->pack(); 



?>
```

just move `file_put_contents("minified.js", $packer->pack());`above header, and it'll works.

Comment: Nope, no effect

Comment: i've tested and its working! doesn't it write all buffer data to minified.js?

Comment: It works, the data writes it to minified.js ok, but when I change the data in minified.php, the data is not automatically updated in minified.js

Comment: what you are changing in minified.php?

Comment: Several .js files are attached to minified.php. They merge into one and then minify. The output then changes dynamically at each change in JS files. I need this change to be written into minified.js also (dynamic output copying)

Comment: I've updated my answer! Get old data then merge it with new!

Comment: Still not working, minified.js does not automatically update itself, and it also does a "double" output

Comment: if you made changes to JSs it won't update automatically without running php file.

Comment: This is the problem. Is there a way to solve it? The output in minified.php changes automatically when you change JS perfectly. However, the output minified.js does not update.

Comment: You may go through AJAX or WEBSOCKETS. both are hard.

Comment: Well, I wanted to save my job, but as I see it will be even worse. It will be easier to copy content to minified.js manually in the filing phase.